# How do I capture events from multiple dropdown-menus in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that contains multiple dropdown menus for a list of profile images.  I've tagged the list element with the DB id of the photo so I can perform the associated action. I've coded my table to look like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><img src="/photos/files/5/m/131309a4fb918110ed1061e90a715eca.jpeg"/></td><td><div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> User</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="5"><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
    <li id="5"><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="/photos/files/5/m/b19102d8ba1158e2a139ffa84e8e8540.jpeg"/></td><td><div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> User</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="7"><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
    <li id="7"><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

My jquery attempt is below but isn't working:

```
    $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(e){

         if ($(this).attr('class')=='icon-pencil') {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert("ID= " + id);
         }

    });
```

I never hit my alert code so what am I missing here?

Also is there a better way to track the photo ID's or will they work this way?

Comment: why you don't try $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(e)...

Comment: Still can't reach my alert msg ???

Comment: $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li', function() {}); is more effective because it a) binds the event listener only to .dropdown-menu and b) you can add new list-elements during runtime. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have li > a > .icon-pencil in your structure but you're looking for this.className on li click (which is, obviously, the li). Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(){
    if ($(this).find('icon-pencil').length > 0) {
        var id = this.id;
        alert("ID= " + id);
    }
});
```

A cleaner approach would be to listen for click on the anchor, since this is the usual click element:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(){
    if ($(this).children('.icon-pencil').length > 0) {
        var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
        alert("ID= " + id);
    }
    return false;
});
```

And the cleanest solution would be to set the ID's only on .dropdown-menu, so they are unique, then get it via .closest('ul') instead of .closest('li').

PS: having duplicate IDs is always bad.

Comment: That works!  Any sugestions for a better way to store/retrieve duplicate IDs?